# How to use typewriter fonts in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, typewriter

How can we use teletypewriter fonts in math mode? In the following code, `$X_i$` still comes italic and non-typewriter font. `$\texttt{fnfoo(X_i)}$` gives errors "Missing $ inserted".

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\texttt{fnfoo()}

\texttt{fnfoo($X_i$)}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\mathtt{X_i}` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As its name suggests, `\texttt` operates on text-mode material; by design, it does *not* operate on math-mode material that may occur in its argument.

To typeset math-mode material using the (math) monospaced font, you need to encase it in a `\mathtt` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\begin{document}
\texttt{fnfoo()}

\texttt{fnfoo($X_i$)}           % not good

\texttt{fnfoo($\mathtt{X_i}$)}  % better
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\mathop` to declare the function and `\mathtt` to select the tt font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fnfoo}{\mathop{\mathtt{fnfoo}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

$\fnfoo()$

$\fnfoo(X_i)$

\end{document}
```